# Problema al concatenar una variable con texto javascript

Tags: javascript

En la función cv() se guarda una cadena en la variable mandar(variable global) y tengo problemas para que se concatene dentro de la función cartas.forEach(), ¿alguien sabe por que?

```
var tablero = document.getElementById('tablero');
var cartas = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
var parejas = cartas.length;
var primerCarta = 0;
var segundaCarta = 0;
var mandar;

//creando cartas de forma aleatoria y generando pares
cartas = cartas.concat(cartas);
cartas = cartas.sort(function() {
return Math.random() - 0.5
});

function cv(){
var seleccion = document.getElementById("text").value;
if (seleccion === "a"){
  mandar = "terrestre";
}else if (seleccion ==="b"){
 mandar = "agua";
}else if (seleccion ==="c"){
  mandar = "aves";
}
}


 cartas.forEach(function(val) {
var div = document.createElement('div');
var imagen = document.createElement('img');
imagen.src = "img-pop/" + (mandar + (val)) + ".jpg";
imagen.className = "tarjeta";
div.id = val;
div.className = "tarjetas"
//console.log(val);
div.appendChild(imagen);
tablero.appendChild(div);

 div.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
 var tarjetatocada = event.target;
 if (primerCarta !== 0 && segundaCarta !== 0) {
 // limpiar banderas
  if (primerCarta.id !== segundaCarta.id) {
    primerCarta.classList.remove('abrir');
    segundaCarta.classList.remove('abrir');
  };
  primerCarta = 0;
  segundaCarta = 0;
  };

  tarjetatocada.classList.add('abrir');
  if (primerCarta === 0) {
  primerCarta = tarjetatocada;
  } else {
  segundaCarta = tarjetatocada;
  if (primerCarta.id === segundaCarta.id) {
    parejas = parejas - 1;
    console.log(parejas);
    }
    if (parejas === 0) {
    //console.log('Ganaste', parejas);
    alert("Ganaste!");
    detenerse();

    //location.reload();
    }
    }
    if (primerCarta === segundaCarta){
    };
    }, true)
    });
```

Comment: agrega el html por favor

Comment: veo que  a la función le pasas una variable val pero no la noto en otra parte del código, esa para que es?

Comment: pues por como esta el codigo, mandar se modifica dentro de una funcion. y el foreach por fuera de la funcion, asi que "mandar" va a ser undefined

Comment: la utilizo en imagen.src  la penúltima linea del código, es para que dependiendo del valor de "mandar" , pueda agregar las imagenes alojadas en la carpeta"img-pop"

Comment: entonces como puedo solucionarlo y que ya no sea undefined?

Comment: Imagino que tu variable esta declarada al inicio fuera de todo, pues en ese caso si sería global (EVER MUESTRA)[https://jsfiddle.net/zhygqfza/4/]

Comment: @ShadowPaz `val` en este caso es el parametro que nos pasa la función callback de [`foreach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) de javascript. Lo que no me queda claro es que contiene la variable `cartas`. @Daniel ¿Es el código completo? Parece que le faltan muchas partes. Revisa [mcve]

Comment: añadire el codigo completo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

la variable mandar llega al foreach sin valor

```
var mandar = "esteeselvalorinicialquedariaundefinedsinestalinea";

function cv(){
  var seleccion = document.getElementById("text").value;
  switch (seleccion) {
      case "a":
         mandar = "terrestre";
         break;
      case "b":
         mandar = "agua";
         break;
      case "c":
         mandar = "aves";
         break;
      default:
         mandar = "noseleccionado";
  }
}

/* descomentar la siguiente linea para usar los valores segun la funcion cv  */
// cv();
  cartas.forEach(function(val) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var imagen = document.createElement('img');
  imagen.src = "img-pop/" + (mandar + (val)) + ".jpg";
  imagen.className = "tarjeta";
```

Nota 1: Te reemplacé los if else if por un switch para poder poner ahi un default value que no sea global

Nota 2: el foreach se ejecuta una sola vez, tal vez haya que ponerlo en una funcion y llamarlo desde cv?

Comment: Gracias alo Malbarez lo probare de las dos formas , siento que lo mas viable es ponerlo dentro de una función.